# AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR or something else?

Tags: android, admob

My application is ready, and i have admob into it. I also have the AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR used for fetching the add. Is it right way or its just the testing way to fetch add. Will i get reveue in live application if i use AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `AdRequest.addTestDevice(TEST_EMULATOR)` is the way to fetch the add during testing.  However, this piece of code will only fetch test ads from emulators.  Everyone running your app on a device will get live ads, and you'll get revenue when users click on those live ads.

Even if you used `AdRequest.addTestDevice("YOUR_DEVICE_ID")` to get test ads on your device, this only requests test ads on that one specific device, and every other device will get live ads.  You don't have to worry about your users getting test ads once you release.