# Google ads in android app

Tags: android, admob

I am working with adding Google ads in android apps...
my code is as follows

```
adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.SMART_BANNER, "xxxxxxxxxx");

LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);

layout.addView(adView);

AdRequest ads=new AdRequest();

ads.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);

adView.loadAd(ads);
```

all is working fine on emulator but doesn't show ads on my device
please suggest me what i'm doing wrong here

Comment: I need your logcat errors OR warnings.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `AdRequest.addTestDevice(TEST_EMULATOR)` is the way to fetch the add during testing. However, this piece of code will only fetch test ads from emulators. Everyone running your app on a device will get live ads, and you'll get revenue when users click on those live ads.

Even if you used `AdRequest.addTestDevice("YOUR_DEVICE_ID")` to get test ads on your device, this only requests test ads on that one specific device, and every other device will get live ads. You don't have to worry about your users getting test ads once you release.

To get `DEVICE_ID` check [this](http://webhole.net/2011/12/02/android-sdk-tutorial-get-admob-test-device-id/).

This is said by Eric Leichtenschlag [Developer Programs Engineer for Google, specializing in Google AdMob Ads SDK support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9573980/1405983).

You need to check [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-admob-ads-sdk/rEbR-PjRwAQ/alo9g5tuebQJ).

Comment: How can I get my device id?

Comment: @Amol Please check [this](http://webhole.net/2011/12/02/android-sdk-tutorial-get-admob-test-device-id/).

Comment: Its my pleasure. Glad to help you.

Comment: one stupid query why i'm not getting live ads on my device while emulator is providing live ads